# Corrupted eclipse toolbars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After installing MercurialEclipse to my standard android environment (Eclipse + ADT plugin) I noticed that my toolbars in idea are corrupted like on the attached screen (gaps).

[image]

Also I observe that splash screen during ide launching changed to default from Eclipse (not for Android Env).

Do you have any suggestions how can I fix these issues, especially this with tool bars?

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the following file (best way with a closed eclipse, starting after deletion):

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Start your eclipse with following flag:

```
-clearPersistedState
```